# Problems with MAMP actualization

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I am designing a website using WordPress and I am hosting it locally with MAMP (Mac). Yesterday I was using the 5.1 version of MAMP and today I have actualized it to the 5.2.

I am saving image files in wp-content/themes/(mythemename)/images/ to use them later on when editing the html in the WordPress dashboard. But it no longer finds the new image files (after the MAMP) actualization.

I could see, that after the actualization I had two MAMP folders in Applications. I deleted the 5.1 version one.

When I start the servers with MAMP 5.2 it looks like is working perfectly but then it seems that I am working with the old version files when editing my page in the WordPress dashboard.

Sorry if I can't explain myself better, but I have tried a lot of stuff and didn't work. Has anyone faced this issue before? Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer myself right away after posting this question. (lol)
It was a problem with cache and cookies. Nothing like to delete the history of the browser to solve this kind of issues.

I leave this here in case someone else faces the same kind of problem.